# Why di I keep getting this Error? (8,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I´m creating a stored procedure with PL/SQL to create an automatic password with a desired format.
The desired format comes from the employee table and from there is where different data is taken.

I kept receiving this error, Error(8,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
My code is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_password(e_id NUMBER)
IS
    nuevo_password employees.password%TYPE; 

begin
    nuevo_password := lower(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 1, 1)) || lower(LAST_NAME) ||  employee_id || SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 3);

    select nuevo_password into password from employees; 
    UPDATE employees SET password = nuevo_password WHERE employee_id = e_id;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El password para el empleado' || e_id || 'se ha generado exitosamente');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El nuevo password es: ' || nuevo_password);
END;
```

I want the stored procedure to only be used once the user is created in the table employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the errors I get (after creating the `employees` table) are not just "Error(8,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored" but

```
LINE/COL   ERROR
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------
6/5        PL/SQL: Statement ignored
6/36       PLS-00201: identifier 'FIRST_NAME' must be declared
9/5        PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/32       PLS-00201: identifier 'PASSWORD' must be declared
9/41       PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

so it would be worthwhile finding out how to report compilation errors in whatever tool you are using.

The errors are telling you that `FIRST_NAME` and `PASSWORD` are not declared as variables.

Once you've declared the missing variables, you'll need to populate them using a `select into` construction, specifying the employee_id. Personally, I would fetch the entire employee row into a record, rather than managing multiple separate variables.

```
create or replace procedure set_password(e_id number)
is
    emp employees%rowtype;
begin
    select * into emp
    from   employees e
    where  e.employee_id = e_id; 

    emp.password :=
        lower(substr(emp.first_name, 1, 1)) ||
        lower(emp.last_name) ||
        emp.employee_id ||
        substr(emp.phone_number, 1, 3);

    update employees e
    set    password = emp.password
    where  employee_id = e_id;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('El password para el empleado ' || e_id || ' se ha generado exitosamente');
    dbms_output.put_line('El nuevo password es: ' || emp.password);
end set_password;
```

Test values:

```
create table employees
( employee_id
, first_name
, last_name
, phone_number
, password )
as
select 123
     , 'Karl'
     , 'Marx'
     , '07345678910'
     , cast('' as varchar2(50))
from dual;
```

```
call set_password(123);

El password para el empleado 123 se ha generado exitosamente
El nuevo password es: kmarx123073
```

From a security perspective, are you sure you want to generate a predictable password? If it was me, I would prefer to just set it to `dbms_random.string('a',10)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, with this explanation I can see where my error was. I will consider your contribution, but it work already with the format that i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with below line:

```
nuevo_password := lower(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 1, 1)) || lower(FIRST_NAME) ||  employee_id || SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 3);
```

You have two options either select the values of FIRST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER in a variable using select query and then concatenate or else write a select into query and save this concatenation into nuevo_password variable.

Comment: Thank you, yeah i see now where my error was. I needed to have the values in a variable. So I will make a few changes in my code.